# CreateWindowEx returns NULL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++-2010, createwindowex

The following is a portion of my code. Every time I run the program, `CreateWindowEx` of the SPanel returns `NULL`, triggering an error. Can anyone see what is wrong with this piece of code?

`SPanelProc` and `MainWndProc` are declared already, and is of the prototype `LRESULT CALLBACK SPanelProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);`.

The environment I'm programming in is Visual C++ 2010.

Why is `CreateWindowEx` always returning `NULL`?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WindowsX.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK SPanelProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void Init ()
{
    HWND child;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)(GetWindowLongPtr (parent, GWLP_HINSTANCE));
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    const char PanelClassName[] = "SPanel"; //ClassName of the panel. Do not reuse on another window

    //Create the window, initialize GWLP_USERDATA, check for errors, register the window class, and hide the window


    //Create the windowclass for the button
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = SPanelProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon (hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor (hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = PanelClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon (hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    //If could not register window class
    if(!RegisterClassEx (&wc))
    {
        MessageBox (NULL, "Panel registration failed!", "Error!", MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        return;
    }

    //Create window
    child = CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY, PanelClassName, "TITLE_TEXT", WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 400, 200, parent, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    //Check for error in window creation
    if (child == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox (NULL, "Panel creation failed!", "Error!", MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        return;
    }

    return;
}


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG Msg;
    int length, width;

    //Register the window, create the window, and check for errors
    {
        //Window class
        wc.cbSize        = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style         = 0;
        wc.lpfnWndProc   = MainWndProc;
        wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        wc.hInstance     = hInstance; //Instance used to create the window
        wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDI_CODERICON)); //Change here to change large application icon
        wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor (hInstance, IDC_ARROW); //Change here to change application cursor
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1); //Change here to change starting background color (white)
        wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = Coder::Constants::MAINWNDCLASSNAME;
        wc.hIconSm       = (HICON)LoadImage (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDI_CODERICON), IMAGE_ICON, GetSystemMetrcs (SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSMICON), 0); //Change here to change application icon (small, as in taskbar)

        //Register the window class so that the ClassName can be used to create the window and then check for error
        if (!RegisterClassEx (&wc))
        {
            MessageBox (NULL, "Main window registration failed!", "Error!", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }

        //Get screen dimensions
        length = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN);
        width = GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN);

        //Create window
        hWnd = CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, /*Border*/
            Coder::Constants::MAINWNDCLASSNAME,
            Coder::Constants::MAINWNDTITLETEXT, /*Title of window*/
            WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, /*Window style*/
            (length - Coder::Constants::XDEFAULT - Coder::Constants::XSHIFT) / 2, (width - Coder::Constants::YDEFAULT - Coder::Constants::YSHIFT) / 2, /*Top-left x and y coordinates*/
            Coder::Constants::XDEFAULT + Coder::Constants::XSHIFT, Coder::Constants::YDEFAULT + Coder::Constants::YSHIFT, /*Lengths and widths of window*/
            NULL, NULL, 
            hInstance, NULL);

        //Check for error in window creation
        if (hWnd == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox (NULL, "Main window creation failed!", "Error!", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //Call function
            Init (hWnd);

    //Show and redraw the window
    ShowWindow (hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow (hWnd);

    //Put window in message loop
    while (GetMessage (&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) //While not terminated
    {
        TranslateMessage (&Msg);
        DispatchMessage (&Msg);
    }

    //Return
    return static_cast<int>(Msg.wParam);
}
```

Comment: How does `SPanelProc()` handle `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE`? Does it return `TRUE` when handling `WM_NCCREATE` and `0` when handling `WM_CREATE`?

Comment: Where does *parent* come from?  Does it belong to another process?  That's not possible.

Comment: Can you include some output from GetLastError?  You might be able to use it to diagnose your problem.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try `GetLastError` and `FormatMessage` to potentially get some info on why it's failing. Usually it's because you have an invalid parameter like conflicting styles etc.

Comment: I suspect an error in your wnd proc.  Can you post that code?

Comment: SPanelProc () does not handle the mentioned messages. GetLastError () returned a DWORD with value 0. I have updated the code to be more complete. Thank you for helping and looking over this complicated code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every window procedure MUST return `DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wparam,lparam)` on every message, with exceptions on messages like `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT` when you are using your custom painting procedure (you must return 0 so the OS doesn't the repaint the window with it's default procedure)

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. I thought I could finalize the creation and then deal with the WndProc, but it looks like that is not true. Thank you all! I have upvoted everyone and mark you as the answer.